# Syntax Error in React Native for Android Development

Tags: android, react-native

```
import { View, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Heading from './Heading'
import Input from './Input'

class App extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super()
        this.state = {
            input value: '',
            todos: [],
            type: 'All'
        }

        inputChange (inputValue) {
            this.setState({inputValue})
        }
    }
  render () {
    const {todos, inputValue, type } = this.state
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
                        style={styles.content}>
                            <Heading />
                            <Input
                            input Value={inputValue}
                            inputChange={(text) => this.inputChange(text)} />

            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    ) 
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
    },
    content: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 60
    }
})

export default App
```

"So I have this error that I have tried to fix through disabled eslint and it's not working. This is my first time using react-native. I'm taking a class and this is for an assignment of mine to create a TodoApp. My teacher gave us the exact code he wanted us to input into VSCode, so we could then make changes to it accordingly for the assignment. I was halfway through his video, and this error kept coming up, but not for him. I have looked all around for an answer and can't seem to find one. The section of code that gives me a problem in the inputChange (inputValue) and say it's missing a semicolon. In the video the teacher doesn't put one and it works completely fine. I've done some reading that it could be eslint, but I've tried to disable it and it still doesn't work."[image]

Answer (score 0):

change position of inputChange function from inside of constructor to body of class ( after closing constructor )

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
  inputChange(inputValue) {
    // ...
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>{/* rest of code */}</>
    );
  }
}
```

### Edit

you may name properties incorrect

[image]

Comment: When I do that it gives me a render error and Ill send the pic for you to look at. I have tried this already, but not sure why it's giving me the render error. https://gyazo.com/e91b2020a1290994f97ff89982db70ce

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you are attempting to define the method `inputChange` inside the `constructor` method, which is not possible. You need to close the `constructor` method definition before defining your `inputChange` method. I recommend taking a closer look at the code your instructor provided. I suspect that on closer inspection you will find one curly brace closing the `setState` function and another curly brace closing the `constructor` method before that `inputChange` method definition starts.

Comment: When I do that it gives me a render error and Ill send the pic for you to look at. I have tried this already, but not sure why it's giving me the render error. gyazo.com/e91b2020a1290994f97ff89982db70ce

Comment: There is a type in the code you originally posted.
`this.state = { input value: ''`
should be `inputValue: '',`. Does that typo exist in your code?

Comment: It doesn't exist I have it as inputValue: ' ',